# Group Collection by value

Tags: c#, linq

I have these two classes:

```
class ZoneInformation : Scores
{
    public string Zone {get;set;}
}

class Scores
{
    public string TypeQ {get;set;}
    public int High {get;set;}
    public int Low {get;set;}
}
```

I make a collection like this: Zones and 3 different Types in every one:

```
Collection<ZoneInformation> Values = new Collection<ZoneInformation>();

Values.Add(new ZoneInformation{TypeQ="Type1", Zone="Zone1", High=5, Low=6});
Values.Add(new ZoneInformation{TypeQ="Type2", Zone="Zone1", High=7, Low=8});
Values.Add(new ZoneInformation{TypeQ="Type3", Zone="Zone1", High=9, Low=10});

Values.Add(new ZoneInformation{TypeQ="Type1", Zone="Zone2", High=11, Low=12});
Values.Add(new ZoneInformation{TypeQ="Type2", Zone="Zone2", High=13, Low=14});
Values.Add(new ZoneInformation{TypeQ="Type3", Zone="Zone2", High=15, Low=16});
```

How can I "group" the elements of my 'Values' collection by all the Zones? like this

```
new Scores{TypeQ="Type1", High=16, Low=18});
```

As you can see High=5+11, the sum the two 'Type1'

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is pretty straightforward with Linq:

```
var groups = Values.GroupBy(zi => zi.TypeQ)
                   .Select(g => new Scores
                         {
                         TypeQ = g.Key, 
                         High  = g.Sum(zi=> zi.High), 
                         Low   = g.Sum(zi=> zi.Low)
                         }
              );
```

Answer (score 1):

What the others said, or in another syntax:

```
var res = from q in Values
          group q by q.TypeQ into x
          select new Scores()
          {
              TypeQ = x.Key,
              High = x.Sum( y => y.High ),
              Low = x.Sum( y => y.Low ),
          };
```